# Separate item in foreach tag (jstl)

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

I have a JSP page with JSTL and I want to separate an user from other with an `<hr>` tag. How can I solve it?

```jsp
<c:forEach var="user" items="${list_users}">    
    <c:out value="${user.name}"/>
    <c:out value="${user.surname}"/>
</foreach>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a table to draw each user in the cell, then put `<hr>`

```
<table>
<c:forEach var="user" items="${list_users}">  
<tr><td>  
 <c:out value="${user.name}"/><br>
 <c:out value="${user.surname}"/><br>
<hr>
</td></tr>
</c:foreach>
</table>
```

Comment: I inserted name and surname in different cell of a same row .I created a new row with `<tr><td colspan="2"><hr></td></tr>` and it works.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Put it inside the loop and use `varStatus` attribute of `c:forEach` to remove the one line you don't need in the end.

```
<c:forEach var="user" items="${list_users}" varStatus="status">
  <c:out value="${user.name}" />
  <c:out value="${user.surname}" />
  <c:if test="${not status.last}">
    <hr />
  </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: With your code i have 1)break_line 2)user1_info 3)User2_info.But i want 1)user1_info 2)break_line 3)user2_info